# Formatter Black is not working on save (VSC)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, python-black, black-code-formatter

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
  },
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html"
  },
  "prettier.printWidth": 140,
  "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

I have uninstalled VSC
and set it up from beginning.
I don't know why formatter is not working on save.
It works when I format my file in terminal.

Comment: Is your **Prettier** extension working for `.jsonc` files when you format them?

Comment: they prettier is able to format json file too

Comment: It's weird, could you open the `OUTPUT` panel and choose `Python` channel. Then save the file again to get the outputs? And could you verify whether you have modified the path of `black` in the User settings.json file?